# end of file reached error in pusher-websocket-ruby gem

Tags: ruby, pusher

I'm getting "**end of file reached**" error in an infinite loop after a several hours of connection (3-4 hours) using pusher-websocket-ruby gem. I also listen **pusher:error** event but it doesn't catch anything. Also the connection of the subscribed channel lost after this error.  Does anybody face with this problem? Any ideas how to prevent infinite loop and connection lose?

My gem version is 0.15.1 https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-ruby

```
  require 'pusher-client'
  options = {:secret => 'secret_key'}

  socket = PusherClient::Socket.new("key",options)
  socket.connect(true) # Connect asynchronously
  socket.subscribe('socket_name')

  socket.bind('pusher:error') do |data|
    PusherClient.logger.fatal("Pusher : error : #{data.inspect}")
  end

  socket['socket_name'].bind("test") do |data|
    #my business
  end

  loop do
    sleep(1)
  end
```

**EDIT:**

Error logs

```
D, [2014-10-18T06:42:46.705047 #9564] DEBUG -- : end of file reached
D, [2014-10-18T06:42:46.705102 #9564] DEBUG -- : end of file reached
D, [2014-10-18T06:42:46.705158 #9564] DEBUG -- : end of file reached
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue, not a question... what are you asking? Maybe you can edit the question and add the error message details (log), so we can look up the details...?

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks for warning Myst